# Client socket hang up

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am stuck in an error.

We have a rest_server and rest_client in node.js.

Now when I call server API from client and if server is unable to response up-to 2 minute then it shows in client side, I need to handle it on client side:

> Error: server hang up

I am unable to handle this issue. I just want either to increase its time more than 2 minute or it should not hang up any of time.

Note: server doesn't send any response in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this assigning a new timeout to the request object like this

```
request.setTimeout(myTimeoutInMiliseconds[, optionalCallbackFunction]);
```

The callback function is optional. You've got more info on nodejs documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_settimeout_timeout_callback)

Comment: Sure thing. Let me now how it goes and If it doesn't work I'll try to think up something

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var server = app.listen(5000);

server.listen(3000);

server.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("A new connection was made by a client.");
    socket.setTimeout(50 * 1000); 
    // set timeout for 50 seconds. Change this to your requirement.
})
```

Comment: Ok and thanks for the prompt response, let me check and revert back to you with the result.

Comment: Its not solution of my problem I am still stuck, what I need I just want to increase time of socket hang up up-to 10 minutes.

Comment: I am sorry but I think there is some miscommunication, I need solution for client not for server and I want to increase up-to 10 minutes code in client not in server.

Comment: Please update your question, and mention to handle from client side